# Having issues removing old tile

Tags: wood, flooring, slab, vinyl

I recently started a project to do new floors throughout a house I just bought. We are gonna do about 1600 sq ft in total including the kitchen 2 living rooms, dinning room, and hall. Previously the floors were linoleum that I ripped up and part of the house was the slab concrete and a area in the kitchen, the dinning room and front door entry way are old tile that the original owners probably installed. I tried to get the tiles up using a hammer and chisel but only succeeded in breaking the edges and was unable to get underneath the tile to break it up. At this point I was thinking of floating the living room up to where the tile is to level it to install a wood vinyl hybrid. The other side I may be able to use leveling compound to gradually increase the height to where the tile is. The old linoleum was just put on top and you could tell the areas that were not level in one side of the dinning room and the other side they installed carpet to deal with this issue. I am searching for options in either raising the subfloor or ways to get up old tile which may be porcelain, I am not fully sure but I know it is difficult to get up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you were not able to do it by hand rent a power chipper, these are electric and have a blade that vibrates back and forth and this makes fast work of tile. I also have used an air chizzle with a wide blade. The problem may also be your technique I have not had two much trouble popping tile off with a flat chizzle, the trick is to hit them from the side at the base, many times they will break loose with 1 good smack. If you are striking down on the tile I have seen tile hold up to a hammer dropped from 8' that was well set to a concrete floor so a change in how you are trying to chip them up may save a rental fee.

Comment: I rented a power chipper to get the linoleum up as heat and a scrapper wasn't working, I was pounding the tile from the side with not much ground made, I watched plenty of videos and tried a couple different things without being able to get the tile up

Answer (score 1):

I too use a power chipper.  It removes 90% of the floor.  For the rest I use the chisel/hammer.  In few places, portion of tile remain, I use a grinder to remove the most stubborn pieces.

Can you add few pictures?